# View pdf file from laptop to android

Tags: android, pdf

I'm working on an application to view pdf files.

I have done viewing pdf files from the internet using the docs.google api. I want to try to make my laptop as the server or where the pdf file is located.

```
    WebView webView=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2F10.0.2.2%2Fdrayber_beep%2FAndroid13Web.pdf");
```

The docs.google api cannot find the location, but when I try to click the download link given by the api, I was able to download it in the emulator and view it using a pdf reader.

Am I missing something? I would really appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: I can't see the part `setContentView(webview);` in your code! Have you used it?

Answer (score 0):

The url postet into a browser returns an Bad Request - Error.
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2F10.0.2.2%2Fdrayber%2Handbook.pdf

Comment: yes because its only available in my laptop. I put the pdf file inside my phpadmin folder drayber together with my php scripts.

Comment: please try this link since the location posted above is incorrect.
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2F10.0.2.2%2Fdrayber_beep%2FAndroid13Web.pdf

Comment: Yes, but if it is only available at your labtop, how should Android WebView receive it? The request is send via DNS, resolving docs.google.com to an external IP which won't be your computer unless you have setup some routings including port - forwarding and manipulation the router on your android device or connected Android to your internet via WLAN and setup your WLAN - router to serve your local 192.168.0.x - adress when requesting docs.google.com

Comment: ah, I see: You are passing in your URL into the request to docs.google.com

Comment: I solve the problem through putting the pdf available online(putting it on a www.mysite.com/document.sample.pdf) in order for the docs.google api to read it.

Comment: Yes, thats maybe the reason why the docs.google cannot locate the pdf. thanks for your help :)